# What is a proper context to write such proof by case style?

Tags: math-mode, proof-package

I am writing some proofs in `latex` and currently I would like to follow the standard procedure to organize my proofs in the following way:

[image]

I know how to use the `latex math` mode, as well as some context like `equation` or `align`. However, I just cannot figure out how should I start each proof with a `case` aligned on the left...

Could anyone shed some lights in this problem? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Do you want to number the cases?

Comment: @Bernard, no I don't need to number the case.

Comment: I would use  a `description` environment.

Comment: If you decide in favor of `description` have a look at `enumitem`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick, simple solution; you can create a new kind of itemized list with `enumitem`. Here you have to manually insert `\newline`s though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,enumitem,newpxtext}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\dbracket}{[\![}{]\!]}    

\newlist{caselist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[caselist]{
  label=\textsl{Case},
  labelindent=0pt, %customize value for distance from left margin to "Case"
  leftmargin=4em, %customize value for distance from left margin to item content
  labelsep=*,
  align=left
}

\begin{document}
\noindent Text before
\begin{caselist}
  \item {\(f_{Z} \dbracket{x \coloneqq 0}(\sigma_{i}) = [x \mapsto Z]\sigma_{i}\)}:\newline{}
    Assume \(c_{i} = E, n\) and \(\alpha(E) = \sigma_{i}\)\newline{}
    Thus \(\sigma_{i+1} = f_{Z} [\![x \coloneqq 0]\!](\sigma_{i}) = [x \mapsto Z] \alpha(E)\)\newline{}
    etc.
  \item \(f_{Z} \dbracket{x \coloneqq 0}(\sigma_{i}) = [x \mapsto N]\sigma_{i}\) where \(m \ne 0\):\newline{}
    Assume \(c_{i} = E, n\) and \(\alpha(E) = \sigma_{i}\)\newline{}
    etc.
\end{caselist}
\noindent Text after
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: How do I number the cases?

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam The quickest would be to swap `\newlist{caselist}{itemize}{1}` with `\newlist{caselist}{enumerate}{1}` and `label=\textsl{Case}` with `label=\textsl{Case \arabic*}`.